# Match ergonomics and & pattern

Tags: rust, match-ergonomics

Consider following code

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = (&&0,);
    let (x,) = s; // &&i32
    let (&y,) = s; // &i32
    let (&&z,) = s; // i32

    let t = &(&0,);
    let (x,) = t; // &&i32
    let (&y,) = t; // i32

    let u = &&(0,);
    let (x,) = u; // &i32
    let (&y,) = u; // mismatched types expected type `{integer}` found reference `&_`
}
```

Could someone explain, why `&` pattern behaves differently in every case? I suppose it is tied somehow to match ergonomics, maybe some coercions come into play? But I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct, this is due to [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). The first case should hopefully be self explanatory, but the second and third cases can be a bit counter-intuitive.

In the second case:

- `(x,)` is a non-reference pattern (see the second [example](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html#examples) in the RFC). The `t` tuple reference is dereferenced, and `x` is bound as a `ref` as it also is a non-reference pattern. Note that `t.0` was a reference to begin with, thus resulting in `x` being a double reference.
- `(&y,)` is also a non-reference pattern. The `t` tuple is dereferenced again to a `(&i32,)`. However, `&y` is a reference pattern being matched to a `&i32` reference. Hence `y` is bound with `move` mode and is an `i32`.

In the third case:

- Using the same reasoning as the second case, `u` is dereferenced via `Deref` coercion  to an `(i32,)`, and `x`, a non-reference pattern, is bound in `ref` mode. Hence `x` is an `&i32`.
- Again with the same reasoning as the second case, `u` is dereferenced to an `(i32,)`. The `&y` reference pattern is then matched to an `i32`, a non-reference, which causes an error.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. Out of curiosity, is it possible then to write a pattern for the last scenario such that we bind `i32` type?

Comment: @ZeroXbot You should be able to explicitly dereference the tuple with a reference pattern to avoid match ergonomics kicking in: `let &(z,) = u;`