# What will match ergonomics do when encounters reference pattern?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match-ergonomics

I have read [the rfc 2005](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html), knowing the process of manipulation is a repeated operation. And I say `encounters reference pattern`, I am not talking about encountering reference pattern at the first iteration like the following one:

```rust
let x = &String;
// The binding mode is `move`, so x is of type `&String`
```

But some cases where `binding mode` is shifted to `ref/ref mut` during the previous `non-reference pattern` iteration, and then encounters a `reference pattern`.

I have read the rfc very carefully, and I found this sentence `The *default binding mode* only changes when matching a reference with a non-reference pattern.`, does this mean `reference pattern` will do nothing to the matching process, but someone told me `reference pattern` will reset the binding mode back to the default `move`(see case 2).

There are two cases where the "correct" inferences seem conflict with each other:

> Correct means that the inferred type is the same as the one inferred by the compiler, but I don't know if the inferring process is also correct, which is the reason why I post this question.

```rust
// case 1
let (a, b) = &(&String, &String); // a and b are of type &&String
```

```rust
// case 2
let (&a, &b) = &(&String, &String); // a and b are of type String
```

Inference for case 1:

First, we are matching `&(&String, &String)` against `(a, b)`, and `(a, b)` is `non-reference pattern`, so we deref `&(&String, &String)` and set `binding mode` from `move(default one)` to `ref`. Then we are matching `(&String, &String)` against `(a, b)` , with `ref` binding mode, `a` and `b` are of type `&&String`.

> Why did it stop at matching `(&String, &String)` against `(a, b)`, shouldn't we continue to match `&String` against `a` and `b` respectively?
>
> If we continue, matching `&String` against `a`, `a` is `reference pattern`, what should we do now?

Inference for case 2:

First, we are matching `&(&String, &String)` against `(&a, &b)`, `(&a, &b)` is `non-reference pattern`, so we deref `&(&String, &String)` and set `binding mode` to `ref`. Then we match `(&String, &String)` against `(&a, &b)`, which is basically matching `&String` against `&a`, `&a` is `reference pattern`, so we **reset binding mode back to `move`**, making `a` of type `String`.

Contradiction:

In case 2, when encounters reference pattern, what we do is to reset binding mode to the default `move`. However in case 1(if we didn't stop at that point, keeping matching `&String` against `a`), `a` is also `reference pattern`, if we still reset binding mode to move, then a will have type `&String` instead of `&&String`.

And there is another question, which is `when should this inferring algorithm stop`? In case 1, if the algorithm **should** stop at that point, then everything makes senses.

Comment: This is not duplicate with [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343407/match-ergonomics-and-pattern),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731788/weird-type-when-pattern-matching-references), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641939/what-does-pattern-matching-a-non-reference-against-a-reference-do-in-rust) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625001/why-does-pattern-matching-on-optiont-yield-something-of-type-somet)

Comment: rust is strongly typed, so you can just forget about this and just listen what compiler said when it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Stargateur. Thanks for your comment:) Yep, rust's static checking can guarantee everything in right place, but I still wanna know what is going on under the hood:)

Comment: Why are you assuming the binding mode ever resets to `move` when the RFC literally states "Note that there is no exit from the ref binding mode.", and the state machine shows no transition back to move?

Comment: "Why did it stop at matching `(&String, &String)` against `(a, b)`, shouldn't we continue to match `&String` against a and b respectively?" because it's trivially uninteresting: a binding pattern is a reference pattern *and* always succeeds. `&&String` is matched against `a`, this succeeds, this always succeeded, match ergonomics does not impact it, any time spent on it is wasted.

Comment: @Masklinn, Thanks for your comment. I originally posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731788/weird-type-when-pattern-matching-references), and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71732428/14092446) said so. Maybe I misunderstood the answer? I have seen that sentence and states machine illustration from the RFC, but seems like I didn't get what that mean

Comment: @Masklinn, would you like to post an answer explicitly describing this inference process/algorithm? What will happen on each case? When is the time to stop? I am still kind of confused... Sorry about this:(

Comment: The big question for me is why matching `let (&a, &b) = &(&String, &String);` results with `a` being of type `String`. I would expect it to be `&String`. It is as if matching a reference-pattern (`&a`) the default binding mode is set back to `move`. But this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: @rodrigo, yep, I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731788/weird-type-when-pattern-matching-references) to just to figure it out. After reading the answer of that post, I thought I have understood it. Today I review my old question, finding that I am still confused...

Comment: I've found some discussion about this [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42640#issuecomment-386368289). It looks like this is what was implemented, but it was never documented or even formally agreed.

Comment: I just searched rust forum, some folk said "It's [inconsistent (broken)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64586#issuecomment-599823971) to boot. Also, reader beware, the [implementation does not match the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42640#issuecomment-389685325) in other ways too."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I have found the answer. There are several things to clarify:

1. `match ergonomics` only covers the cases where we are matching `non-reference pattern` against `reference`, so the title of this question is wrong, `match ergonomics` does nothing when encounters `reference pattern`. The algorithm of `match ergonomics` is just something like:

   ```rust
   fn match_ergonomics() {
       if (the reference we are matching is `&xx`) {
           binding_mode = `ref`
       } else if (the reference we are matching is `&mut xx`) {
           if (binding_mode == `ref`) {
               binding_mode = `ref`;
           } else {
               binding_mode = `ref mut`;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `default binding mode` is a concept introduced for `match ergonomics`, but this is not exclusive to the cases covered by `match ergonomics`, it has been integrated into the whole rust matching system.
3. The concept of `reference pattern` can be confusing. In `rfc`:

   > A reference pattern is any pattern which can match a reference without coercion. Reference patterns include bindings, wildcards (`_`), `const`s of reference types, and patterns beginning with `&` or `&mut`.

   While in rust reference, it is just pattern beginning with `&/&mut`.
4. Matching is a recursive process, for every procedure in this recursion, there are several cases depending what [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html) we are encountering, which include the  `match ergonomics` cases.
5. There are actually two situations where we will change the DBD, one is matching `non-reference pattern` against `reference`, and the other is matching `&[mut] pat` against `reference`.

   | matching | against | change to DBM |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | non-ref pattern | reference | set to `ref` or `ref mut` |
   | &[mut] pat | reference | set to `move` |

##### Matching algorithm

```rust
// The terminologies we are using in this algorithm come from rust reference
If no `default binding mode` is set, set the `default binding mode` to `move`.

If the pattern is an identifier pattern:
    If we have explicit `ref`:
        bind by reference;
    else if we have explicit `ref mut`:
        bind by mutable reference;
    else:
        // When explicit `ref/ref mut` are absent
        // default binding mode decides how to bind
        If the binding mode is `move`, bind directly.
        If the binding mode is `ref`, bind by immutable reference.
        If the binding mode is `ret mut`, bind by mutable reference.
    
    If the pattern has an inner pattern, repeat this process with that pattern.

else if the pattern is a `&[mut]` reference pattern:
    // matching `&[mut]` against non-reference triggers
    // a compiler error
    Ensure that we are matching against a `&[mut]` reference.

    Dereference the scrutinee expression.
    Set the binding mode to `move`.  
    Repeat this process with the inner pattern.

else if the pattern is any kind of destructuring pattern:
    Set `T` to the type implied by the pattern.
    Ensure that we are matching against a `T` value or `&[mut] T` reference.
    
    // cases covered by match ergonomics
    If we are matching against a `&T` reference:
        Dereference the scrutinee expression.
        Set the binding mode to `ref`.
    else if we are matching against a `&mut T` reference:
        Dereference the scrutinee expression.
        If the binding mode is `move`, set the binding mode to `ref mut`.


    else
        destructure the value;
    Repeat this process for all fields in the pattern.
```

##### Inference for case 1 and 2

```rust
// case 1
let (a, b) = &(&String, &String); // a and b are of type &&String
```

First procedure: we are matching `(a, b)` against `&(&String, &String)`, which goes into case 3(any other kind of destructuring pattern).  `&(&String, &String)`  is a `&T`, so deref it and set `default binding mode` to `ref`.

Second procedure: we are matching `(a, b)` against `(&String, &String)`, which is basicially matching `a` against `&String`. `a` is a identifier pattern, which goes into case 1. We don't have explicit `ref/ref mut` and `default binding mode` is `ref`, so bind by immutable ref, making `a` of type `&&String`.

All the patterns are matched, recursion is over.

```rust
// case 2
let (&a, &b) = &(&String, &String); // a and b are of type String
```

First procedure: we are matching `(&a, &b)` against `&(&String, &String)`, which goes into case 3. Deref and set `default binding mode` to `ref`

Second procedure: we are matching `(&a, &b)` against `(&String, &String)`, which is basically matching `&a` against `&String`. `&String` is a `reference pattern`, so we goes into case 2, and set `default binding mode` to `move`, `&a = &String`, so a has type `String`

All the patterns are matched, recursion is over.

The algorithm may not be that accurate, welcome people who know this stuff to edit this answer.