# How does reference pattern appear to dereference twice?

Tags: rust

Can someone please explain, per the rules of [match ergonomics (RFC 2005)](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html), how the use of a *single* `&` in a reference pattern appears to dereference the matched value *twice*?

#### Example

Suppose we have a `map: HashMap<i32, bool>`. Consider the expression `map.iter().filter(|entry| ...)`, where the type of `entry` is `&(&i32, &bool)`. Now, what if we pattern-match against `entry` in the following two ways?

```rust
map
    .iter()
    .filter(|entry| {
        let (key1, _) = entry;   // typeof(key1) -> &&i32
        let (&key2, _) = entry;  // typeof(key2) -> i32
    })
```

As far as I understand, both patterns match a reference (to a tuple) using a non-reference pattern, and therefore change the default binding mode to `ref`. But what has me stumped is how the type of `key2` ends up as `i32` and not `&i32`.

According to RFC 2005, here is an attempt to write desugared patterns of the above two:

```rust
let &(ref key1_desugared, _) = entry;    // typeof(key1_desugared) -> &&i32
let &(& ref key2_desugared, _) = entry;  // typeof(key2_desugared) -> &i32
```

Though the type of `key1_desuraged` ends up matching the type of `key1`, the type of `key2_desugared` is `&i32`.

What is the correct way to express the pattern `key2` in desugared form?

#### Playground

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1cb8170b1221fb1dd221db885f8eed8d

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules#comment78519904_28552082

Comment: @Finomnis Pattern matching is unrelated to receiver resolution. I think the issue here is indeed a consequence of the mentioned "match ergonomics" RFC, albeit one that I wouldn't have expected either. (I personally strongly dislike match ergonomics, and judging by the questions we get about them here on Stack Overflow, they have caused a lot of confusion, while their goal was to make Rust _easier_ to use.)

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to note here is that match ergonomics only changes the binding mode for *non-reference patterns* and not [reference patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns). This is equivalent to the second case discussed in the question [Match ergonomics and & pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71343407/4038191). Applying the explanation in the answer to that question:

- `(key1, _)` is a non-reference pattern being matched to a reference, so `entry` is dereferenced to a `(&i32, _)`. Since `key1` is a non-reference pattern, it is now bound with `ref` mode (since the outer binding was dereferenced). As `entry.0` is an `&i32`, `key1` now becomes a reference to a `&i32`, or a `&&i32`.
- `(&key2, _)` is a non-reference pattern, so `entry` is dereferenced to a `(&i32, _)`. `&key2` is then matched to a `&i32` reference. Since `&key2` is a reference pattern, match ergonomics *does not apply*. `key2` is hence an `i32`.

Comment: This is definitely not how I'd read the RFC. First, the code would not compile without match ergonomics, so I don't think you can claim they don't apply. And second, the RFC explicitly states there is no way back once we switched to a `ref` binding mode, which should be done on the outermost tuple pattern.

Comment: @SvenMarnach My wording could have been better - by "match ergonomics doesn't apply" I meant the binding mode for `key2` remains unchanged in the second case. This is because the inner pattern in question `&key2` is a _reference_ pattern, and the match ergonomics RFC, besides the auto deref, only changes the default binding mode for _non-reference_ patterns. We never actually switch to the `ref` binding mode in the second case, because we never match a reference with a non-reference pattern (besides the outermost reference of course, which is dereferenced).

Comment: I agree that this is what appears to be happening, but I still find it impossible to interpret the RFC wording this way. I don't even think the wording is ambiguous; it clearly specifies a different behaviour.